# how to get list of all public tweets into iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, xcode4.2

I want list of all public tweets which are containing particular twitter username into  iPhone without login and without using web view and i want to display all these tweets in tableview. For example, when i enter the username (amirkhan), it has to show the following image.

[image]

Please help me how to solve this. Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [Twitter REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api), looks like [search request API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) is exactly what you need (add "from:username" to request to filter twits).

If you developing application for iOS5+ you can use [Twitter.framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TwitterFrameworkReference/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011014) from Apple, [TWRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TWRequestClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010942) is very helpful to perform Twitter API requests.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was very helpful for me. I solved and developed the code what i wanted.